# Plotting Tupper's self-referential formula using ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting

For those who are not familiar with `Tupper's self-referential formula`, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula) is the wiki link.

My interest was to plot it. I tried the naive approach using `RegionPlot`, which did not work very well. There was some overflow warning. So I then tried the `lazy` way and Googled it. I found [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TuppersSelf-ReferentialFormula.html).

The version from the .nb files was relatively old. I picked up the "shortest" version:

```
k=960939379918958884971672962127852754715004339660129306651505519271702802395266424689642842174350718121267153782770623355993237280874144307891325963941337723487857735749823926629715517173716995165232890538221612403238855866184013235585136048828693337902491454229288667081096184496091705183454067827731551705405381627380967602565625016981482083418783163849115590225610003652351370343874461848378737238198224849863465033159410054974700593138339226497249461751545728366702369745461014655997933798537483143786841806593422227898388722980000748404719;

Length[IntegerDigits[k]]
```

Now, the exciting line:

```
ArrayPlot[Table[Boole[
        Floor[
        Mod[
        Floor[y/17]*2^(-17*Floor[x]-Mod[Floor[y],17])
        ,2]
        ]>1/2
    ]
    , {y, k, k + 16}
    , {x, 106, 0, -1}
    ]
    ,PixelConstrained -> True
    ,Frame -> False
    ,ImageSize -> 800
]
```

This was the plot:
[image]

The two lines

```
    ,{y, k, k + 16}
    ,{x, 106, 0, -1}
```

did confuses me at first (the order they occur), but then I compared with the graph on wiki, I am happy about it. We are just plotting `x` in reverse order.

**Question:**

If you read [here](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/how-does-tuppers-self-referential-formula-work/), the author talks about the `wrong N` (`k` in here). We have "changed" the code to "make" it work according to the author. The only difference is that we have swapped the axes?

I would really be interested to understand how `ArrayPlot` plots the `x` and `y`.

Something really strange now, if I do

```
ArrayPlot[Table[Boole[
        Floor[
        Mod[
        Floor[y/17]*2^(-17*Floor[x]-Mod[Floor[y],17])
        ,2]
        ]>1/2
    ]
    ,{y, k, k + 16}
    ,{x, 106, 0, -1}
    ]
    ,PixelConstrained -> True
    ,Frame -> False
    ,ImageSize -> 800
    ,Axes -> True
]
```

Only last line, `Axes -> True`, is new. The graph becomes:

[image]

As a comparison, I have taken a screenshot:

[image]

The second graph is missing some of the right hand side as well as some the top. What happened?

How do I plot this graph easily **WITH** axes label?
And if possible, on the `y` axes, using labels like `k` and `k+16` (17)?

Comment: Get rid of the `PixelConstrained` option. It seems to fix the rest of the plot, and I cannot see a difference with or without anyway.

Comment: @MarcoB Just to be clear, when you say you cannot see the difference, do you mean between the graphs or something else? For the two screen shots, they are EXACTLY as they are presented on the screen. That is, the second graph has some parts MISSING on the right hand side.

Comment: @MarcoB See the third picture.

Comment: @MarcoB Just to confirm what you commented, if I take out the `PixelConstrained`, then yes, they are the same.

Comment: Have you tried using a relative `ImageSize` specification, such as `ImageSize -> Scaled[0.75]`, to make sure that the image is not simply too large for your window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps `Frame` and `FrameTicks` will allow you to achieve your aim.

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 Boole[1/2 < 
   Floor[Mod[Floor[y/17] 2^(-17 Floor[x] - Mod[Floor[y], 17]), 2]]]
ctm[nu_] := 
 ArrayPlot[Table[f[j, k], {k, nu, nu + 16}, {j, 106, 0, -1}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, Mesh -> True]
```

In the following the Tupper number has been plotted:

[image]

You can specify your desired tick marks.

Note the "higher resolution" self referential formula (with number [here](http://shreevatsa.appspot.com/code/tupper/bigtupper.N.txt)):

```
g[x_, y_] := 
 Boole[Mod[Floor[Floor[y/61] 2^(-61 x - Mod[y, 61])], 2] == 1]
w[nu_] := 
 ArrayPlot[Table[g[j, k], {k, nu + 60, nu, -1}, {j, 0, 375}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All]
```

Applying to number:

[image]

Note: for `ArrayPlot` the input array is plotted (as suggested by `FrameTicks` are as per matrix entries: row 1 is top row, left column is first column etc), vs the post in hyperlink of OP and the better resolution in which {x,y} are as per plot and hence the "double flip" (see iterators of table and reverse vertical frame ticks).

I have not "corrected" the `FrameTicks` to illustrate matters.

For [play](https://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2015/07/11/more-tupperware/) you can rasterize text and get the number. This question helped me correct an error with my own musings.