# Plotting tupper's function

Tags: plotting

How to plot [Tupper's (so called) self-referential formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula) in Mathematica of course?

I wanted my value of k or N as they call it, to fit in the formula so that I get my result. In those programs that I copied, my value of k gives a noise. I wrote 1 for a black dot, 0 for a white dot and then multiplied the number by 17. So if possible, please tell me how to find the value of k just in case I am missing something.

Comment: see also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87967/1997

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/RecreationalMath/TuppersSelf-ReferentialFormula.nb

```
n = 960939379918958884971672962127852754715004339660129306651505519271\
7028023952664246896428421743507181212671537827706233559932372808741443\
0789132596394133772348785773574982392662971551717371699516523289053822\
1612403238855866184013235585136048828693337902491454229288667081096184\
4960917051834540678277315517054053816273809676025656250169814820834187\
8316384911559022561000365235137034387446184837873723819822484986346503\
3159410054974700593138339226497249461751545728366702369745461014655997\
933798537483143786841806593422227898388722980000748404719

ArrayPlot[
 Table[Boole[1/2 < Floor[Mod[Floor[y/17] 2^(-17 Floor[x] - Mod[Floor[y], 17]), 2]]], 
       {y, n, n + 16}, {x, 105, -2, -1}], PixelConstrained -> True, 
       Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> {All, All}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: following the wiki explination you can do this: `ArrayPlot@ Reverse@Transpose@Partition[IntegerDigits[n/17, 2, 17*106], 17]`. There seems to be some ambiguity in what the x-range should be by the way looking at the above, the wiki page and the various forms in the wolfram link... ( taking x out of range just white pads the ends so it maybe doesn't matter )