# Manipulate Tupper's self-referential formula

Tags: plotting, manipulate

How to  `Manipulate`  $n$ in [Tupper's self-referential formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TuppersSelf-ReferentialFormula.html)?

```
n = 960939379918958884971672962127852754715004339660129306651505519271\
7028023952664246896428421743507181212671537827706233559932372808741443\
0789132596394133772348785773574982392662971551717371699516523289053822\
1612403238855866184013235585136048828693337902491454229288667081096184\
4960917051834540678277315517054053816273809676025656250169814820834187\
8316384911559022561000365235137034387446184837873723819822484986346503\
3159410054974700593138339226497249461751545728366702369745461014655997\
933798537483143786841806593422227898388722980000748404719


solns = {x, y} /. {ToRules[Reduce[1/2 < Floor[Mod[Floor[y/17]
2^(-17 Floor[x] - Mod[Floor[y], 17]), 2]] && 0 <= x <= 105 && 
   n <= y <= n + 16 && (x | y) ∈ Integers, {x, y}]]};

Show[Graphics[
Rectangle[#, # + 1] & /@ ({105 - #[[1]], n - #[[2]]} & /@ solns)], 
AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I tried:

```
 solns = {x, y} /. {ToRules[Reduce[1/2 < Floor[Mod[Floor[y/17]
 2^(-17 Floor[x] - Mod[Floor[y], 17]), 2]] && 0 <= x <= 105 && 
   n <= y <= k + 16 && (x | y) ∈ Integers, {x, y}]]};

Manipulate[Show[Graphics[
Rectangle[#, # + 1] & /@ ({105 - #[[1]], n - #[[2]]} & /@ solns)], 
AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All],{k,n,n+10,1}]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87955) is related.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not clear to me what the OP expects from the `Manipulate` expression he proposes.